# Deactivating a realm in keycloak

Tags: oauth, keycloak, openid-connect

Is there a way to enabled/disable a realm in Keycloak? I'm happy with either UI or API.

A bit of background information:
I have a multi-tenancy setup with a lot of different realms in Keycloak and I might want to make it impossible to login to some of them.

I know this can be achieved by simply deleting the realm but then I'd have to do a complete new realm configuration if I decided to enable/activate that realm again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you just need to disable the Realm:

[image]